# In JavaScript, how to have the code add up randomly generated numbers one by one as it goes through a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addition

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
```

The code above returns a random number between 1 and 100 ten times over, but I can't figure out how to have the code add up those ten numbers one by one **as it goes through the loop**.

I'm not talking about adding them all up at once after getting out of the `for loop`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You already know how to declare variables, how to assign values to them, and how to sum values. You can use that knowledge to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just add them up inside the loop?

```
var added = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var rand = (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));

    added += rand;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7qkjto2t/1/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to think about the "+=" notation in the "added += rand;". Am I correct in thinking that the variable "added" redeclares its value each time another number is added?

Comment: `+=`  is the same as `added = added + rand`, that's how you concatenate things in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to introduce variables to do what you are looking for. This should do it if I understand correctly.

```
var runningTotal = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var randomNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    console.log(randomNumber);
    runningTotal += randomNumber;
    console.log(randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to think about the "+=" notation in the "    runningTotal += randomNumber;". Am I correct in thinking that the variable "runningTotal" redeclares its value each time another number is added?